# Preprocessing 400 million tweets in Python -- faster

Tags: python, twitter

I have 400 million tweets ( actually I think its almost like 450 but never mind ) , in the form :

```
T    "timestamp"
U    "username"
W    "actual tweet"
```

I want to write them to a file initially in the form  "username \t tweet" and then load into a DB . The problem is that before loading into a db, there are a few things I need to do :
1. Preprocess the tweet to remove RT@[names] and urls 
2. Take the username out of "http://twitter.com/username".

I am using python and this is the code . Please let me know how this can be made faster :)

```
'''The aim is  to take all the tweets of a user and store them in a table.  Do this for all the users and then lets see what we can do with it 
   What you wanna do is that you want to get enough information about a user so that you can profile them better. So , lets get started 
'''
def regexSub(line):
    line = re.sub(regRT,'',line)
    line = re.sub(regAt,'',line)
    line = line.lstrip(' ')
    line = re.sub(regHttp,'',line)
    return line
def userName(line):
    return line.split('http://twitter.com/')[1]


import sys,os,itertools,re
data = open(sys.argv[1],'r')
processed = open(sys.argv[2],'w')
global regRT 
regRT = 'RT'
global regHttp 
regHttp = re.compile('(http://)[a-zA-Z0-9]*.[a-zA-Z0-9/]*(.[a-zA-Z0-9]*)?')
global regAt 
regAt = re.compile('@([a-zA-Z0-9]*[*_/&%#@$]*)*[a-zA-Z0-9]*')

for line1,line2,line3 in itertools.izip_longest(*[data]*3):
    line1 = line1.split('\t')[1]
    line2 = line2.split('\t')[1]
    line3 = line3.split('\t')[1]

    #print 'line1',line1
    #print 'line2=',line2
    #print 'line3=',line3
    #print 'line3 before preprocessing',line3
    try:
        tweet=regexSub(line3)
        user = userName(line2)
    except:
        print 'Line2 is ',line2
        print 'Line3 is',line3

    #print 'line3 after processig',line3
    processed.write(user.strip("\n")+"\t"+tweet)
```

I ran the code in the following manner:

```
python -m cProfile -o profile_dump TwitterScripts/Preprocessing.py DATA/Twitter/t082.txt DATA/Twitter/preprocessed083.txt
```

This is the output I get : ( Warning : its pretty big and I did not filter out the small values, thinking, they may also hold some significance )

```
Sat Jan  7 03:28:51 2012    profile_dump

         3040835560 function calls (3040835523 primitive calls) in 2500.613 CPU seconds

   Ordered by: call count

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
528840744  166.402    0.000  166.402    0.000 {method 'split' of 'str' objects}
396630560   81.300    0.000   81.300    0.000 {method 'get' of 'dict' objects}
396630560  326.349    0.000  439.737    0.000 /usr/lib64/python2.7/re.py:229(_compile)
396630558  255.662    0.000 1297.705    0.000 /usr/lib64/python2.7/re.py:144(sub)
396630558  602.307    0.000  602.307    0.000 {built-in method sub}
264420442   32.087    0.000   32.087    0.000 {isinstance}
132210186   34.700    0.000   34.700    0.000 {method 'lstrip' of 'str' objects}
132210186   27.296    0.000   27.296    0.000 {method 'strip' of 'str' objects}
132210186  181.287    0.000 1513.691    0.000 TwitterScripts/Preprocessing.py:4(regexSub)
132210186   79.950    0.000   79.950    0.000 {method 'write' of 'file' objects}
132210186   55.900    0.000  113.960    0.000 TwitterScripts/Preprocessing.py:10(userName)
  313/304    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {len}
```

Removed the ones which were really low ( like 1, 3 and so on)

Please tell me what other changes can be made. Thanks !

Comment: Could you please run it with profiler and tell us what line is the most time consuming? It is difficult to optimize something without profile information.

Comment: The comments in the code make me glad I don't use twitter.

Comment: Well I could be wrong, but I think that your use of the `*` to unpack your argument list is counterproductive: there's no point in using `izip` since (unless I'm wrong) the usage of the `*` will cause the entire data file to be opened and read...

Comment: @Hoons: not really, the * will transform [data] (a list referencing one file object) into [data, data, data] (a list containing three references to a single file object). The file object itself is not read yet. I wouldn't recommend this kind of code for readability though.

Comment: @Ryan : Would be delighted if you could suggest changes to make it more readable.  Would be great.  Should I create a separate post on codeReview for that ?

Comment: @crazyaboutliv, how about just `itertools.izip_longest(data, data, data)`. This is equivalent. You could just use `izip`, because your code will fail anyway if the number of lines in the file isn't a multiple of three.

Comment: if you're substituting a constant string (instead of regular expression), then str.replace would be much faster than re.sub.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) is for.

You have a pipeline that can be broken into a large number of small steps.  Each step is a `Process` which does to get for an item from the pipe, does a small transformation and puts an intermediate result to the next pipe.

You'll have a `Process` which reads the raw file three lines at a time, and the puts the three lines into a Pipe.  That's all.

You'll have a `Process` which gets a (T,U,W) triple from the pipe, cleans up the user line, and puts it into the next pipe.

Etc., etc.

Don't build too many steps to start with.  Read - transform - Write is a good beginning to be sure you understand the `multiprocessing` module.  After that, it's an empirical study to find out what the optimum mix of processing steps is.

When you fire this thing up, it will spawn a number of communicating sequential processes that will consume all of your CPU resources but process the file relatively quickly.

Generally, more processes working concurrently is faster.  You eventually reach a limit because of OS overheads and memory limitations.

Comment: I am coming across this for the first time ! I will read about this and  change the code accordingly, hopefully  able to benefit from the module. ! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Until you run it through a profiler, it is difficult to know what needs to be changed. However, I would suggest that the most likely slowdowns occur where you are creating and running the regular expressions.

Since your file follows a specific format, you may see significant speed increases by using a lex+yacc combo. If you use [python lex+yacc](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/), you won't see as much of a speed increase, but you won't need to muck about with c code.

If this seems like overkill, try [compiling](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.compile) the regular expressions before you start the loop. You can also have chunks of the file run by independent worker threads/processes.

Again though, profiling will reveal what actually is causing the bottleneck. Find that out first, then see if these options will solve the problem.

Comment: To be honest,  I had never run a profiler before. I am in the process of installing line_profiler and getting back to you on this ! Thanks

Comment: @crazyaboutliv: just curious, what is your current processing speed? i.e. how many tweets can you process in 1 minute? and therefore with the current program, how long will it take to process all the tweets? It could turn out that it might be better to just left it to run and enjoy some free time (or work on something else) rather than spending time to work on even faster solution.

Comment: For 13,22,10436 tweets , which is I think 130 million, it took somewhere around 25 minutes :( So , on an average ,  5 million a minute

Comment: @LieRyan That reminds me of the boost motto (I think it was boost at least): To paraphrase: `Why spend three days solving a problem if you can spend 3years building a library to do the same?` ;)

Comment: +1: Compile the regular expressions will have a big improvement.

Comment: @crazyaboutliv: so everything will be finished in 90 minutes; you can spend that time to think about how to import these into the database and what you'd want to do with the data after you had them in a database.

Comment: I have changed it to re.compile, took care of the mistake committed with lstrip and will post the changed code ,  with the profiler output soon :)

Answer (score 3):

str.lstrip is probably not doing what you were expecting:

```
>>> 'http://twitter.com/twitty'.lstrip('http://twitter.com/')
'y'
```

from the docs:

```
S.lstrip([chars]) -> string or unicode

Return a copy of the string S with leading whitespace removed.
If chars is given and not None, remove characters in chars instead.
If chars is unicode, S will be converted to unicode before stripping
```

Comment: Oh that . is.  bad.  Will  rethink the lstrip part :). Thanks !

Comment: @crazyaboutliv It's also rather unnecessary since we do know the offset where the username starts (do we? no idea about twitter but it seems logical). Just doing `name = url[len('http://twitter.com/'):]` with the `len()` call done only once at startup(! no idea how good the python compiler is here) would get rid of the overhead there. No idea how much that is though without profiling

Comment: @Voo: in python len('...') cannot be safely optimized out, since it is possible someone might substitute the built-in len() with their own version which could calculate different value. Therefore, it will be fastest to calculate it outside the loop. However, unlike in C, len() in python is O(1) because calculating string length is just accessing the attribute that stores the length of the string.

Comment: @LieRyan Right - I was only thinking about a single script where we could globally check whether we assigned to len somewhere (although there are probably some tricks to obfuscate the assignment there too), but clearly we could be called from some other script where len was already changed so that's out of the question. And yes I know about python strings (nobody wants c strings - although even in C there are sensible implementations around) but I reckon for 450million calls we should notice the difference between an attribute lookup and loading an int still.

Comment: @crazyaboutliv Why use split instead of the simpler substring assignment? (in all cases!) Seems easier to read and should be a bit faster. Looking at the profiled results string split is rather high in the list. Furthermore locally assigning the global variables should give a speedup as well - global lookups are rather expensive in python.

Comment: @Voo : right . I will try that  in the next iteration. Only in a few cases, a username was "http://www.twitter.com/" instead of the standard "http://twitter.com/" so, substring would not cause any harm at all .  Thanks . And oh, will also  do the local assignment

Comment: @crazyaboutliv: All the lines that looks like `line1 = line1.split('\t')[1]` can be replaced with `line1 = line1[2:]` since in your data format, the first character is always the letter T/U/W while the second character is always a tab.

Comment: @crazyaboutliv: about the username sometimes having www and others not, I can only say that that's twitter's being insane, but you can do a simple check like `if line2[7] == 'w'` then it is the www version so take `line2 = line2[len('http://www.twitter.com/'):]` else it's the non-www version so take `line2 = line2[len('http://twitter.com/'):]`. Of course with the len() calculation done outside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the profiling information, you're spending a lot of time in regexSub. You may find that you can combine your regexps into a single one, and do a single substitution.

Something like:

```
regAll = re.compile(r'RT|(^[ \t]+)|((http://)[a-zA-Z0-9]*.[a-zA-Z0-9/]*(.[a-zA-Z0-9]*)?)|...')
```

(The intention of this is to not only replace all the things you are doing with re.sub, but also the lstrip). I've ended the pattern with ...: you'll have to fill in the details yourself.

Then replace regexSub with just:

```
line = regAll.sub(line)
```

Of course, only profiling will show if this is faster, but I expect that it will as there will be fewer intermediate strings being generated.

Comment: Also, doing the various splits/strips when you get the line, then passing this modified line down the for loop will avoid needing to pass over the input string multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

For preprocessing the tweets, you can use the `tweetprep` Python library.

It can also be used for translating tweets to any other language.

Link to library:
https://pypi.org/project/tweetprep/

Installation:

```
pip install tweetprep
```

Usage:

```
from tweetprep import preprocess
#from tweetprep import lang_translator

tweet = "#COVID-19 is the worst pandemic @2020!! :,("
# get translated tweet
lang="es"
print(preprocess.lang_translator.translate(tweet,dest=lang).text)

# Get processed version of tweet
print(preprocess.clean(tweet))
```

Output:

```
# COVID-19 es la peor pandemia @ 2020!! :,(
covid19 is the worst pandemic crying smiley
```